# How to disable USBboot?

Tags: usb, boot, boot-issues

When i turn on my Raspberry Pi it tries to boot from USB. I plugged in a wireless mouse. Message on monitor:

```
starting USB...
USB0: Core Realses: 2.80a
scanning bus 0 for devices...
```

And nothing going on. I need to skip this and go to LAN boot. How I can disable USB boot?

Comment: it's not booting from USB, it's scanning the USB bus for devices, and I don't even know what "LAN boot" is supposed to mean

Comment: LAN boot mean, thet i load from LAN RDP client and start them. How i can disable this scanning?

Comment: The Raspberry hardware is completely incapable to *directly* boot from USB MSDs (except the RPi3). Even then , i very much doubt that the RPi3 "stage zero" bootrom prints / will print such a message when booting from USB MSDs. So , **what software are you using ???**

Comment: which pi do you have? it might be possible to tell the usb hub to power off and stay powered off through this stage.  You would then have to tell it to power them back on from the rdp client stage.

Answer (score 0):

I get this message, and get stuck at the same place, when trying to boot with the Fedora 25 raspberry images. I've found that unplugging the USB keyboard and mouse from my pi 3 until after it gets past this point allows it to boot. I have not yet found how to reconfigure it so that step is no longer necessary.